# SSIS pointing to old connection

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, etl

I updated a connection in SSIS package as server names for the source DB was changed. 
And we follow the file-based deployment. But when I run back the job it feels like it is still pointing the old database.

Am I missing something? I am totally new to SSIS. Is there any cache in SSIS?

Comment: Is it a Shared Connection? Shared Connection objects are published separately from a report's .rdl file.

Comment: Not sure. But I changed the server name  in connection manager

Comment: If you only have a "feeling" to go on then try opening up SQL Profiler listening on the old server name and the new server name and see which one actually receives the traffic.

Comment: this connection is teradata db

Comment: Start your package with `dtexec ... /Rep V ` and capture the log. You will find connection manager details there.

Comment: Make sure that there is not an expression undoing your hardcode.